# PHP allows user generated session ID with strict_mode enabled

Tags: php, session

As the title suggests, my setup somehow allows me to select any session ID I want, even though strict mode is enabled.

Configuration of PHP is (when running php_info();)

```
session.use_cookies On
session.use_only_cookies On
session.use_strict_mode On
session.use_trans_sid 0
session.cookie_httponly On
session.cookie_secure On
```

I can verify that the session ID can be "user customized" by setting a PHPSESSID cookie for the domain to whatever I want, then logging in by passing this cookie with the login request.

This means anyone could potentially be tricked into setting their cookie ID to "123", and my server would validate their login and let them use this ID for subsequent requests - assuming of course they had the credentials to make "123" a valid session - compromising their identity.

Why is my server not regenerating the ID when it does not exist? I was under the impression this was the whole idea of strict_mode. Am I wrong?

I can confirm that the ID is deleted from the server (memcached in this case) by telnet'ing to it and finding the key - it will delete when logging out and come back when logging in - even if I set it to just 123 or any similar insecure value. If I don't set a cookie when logging in, it will correctly generate a new one.

**Edit:** I fixed it by calling `session_regenerate_id(true);` after a successful login, forcing the cookie to be replaced - but this does not answer the original question.

Comment: Put your solution as an answer to this question. It will help future readers to find it.

Comment: I would, if it was an answer to the question and not an alternative solution :)

Comment: gotcha, you can read more on the matter at https://wiki.php.net/rfc/strict_sessions